# I need to create separate regression equations for data after "set_index" is applied

Tags: python, pandas

I am not even sure if "set_index" is appropriate here but it "looks" as if it worked.  I have a bunch of stock option data and each symbol has multiple days of data with multiple expiration dates for each WRT iv and strike.

```
df.columns=['symbol','exchange','date','adj_close','opt_sym','expiry','strike','call_put','style','ask','bid','mid','iv',
        'volume','oi','fwd_price','override_flag','delta','vega','gamma','theta','rho']
```

I then apply this

```
df.set_index(['symbol', 'date','expiry','exchange'], inplace=True)

df.head(30)
```

and got this
[image]

Comment: my image did not paste . . .i have a table which looks to be broken down into 'symbol' on far left, then within the symbol the 'date' and then within date the expiry.  thank you

Comment: What's the question?  What have you tried already and what about it isn't working?  So far all you seem to have done here is printed out a multi-indexed dataframe...

Comment: i am trying to extract the iv data 13th column and regress it against the strike (7th column) by symbol/date/expiry bucket and i have no idea how to treat each stock/expiry/date as a unique df.  I then want to have the regression coefficients be accessible by the same symbol/expiry/date bucket for further calculations afterwards.  If i just had one symbol/expiry/date bucket I have no trouble generating 4th order coefficients so i have that part figured out.  Sorry for the poorly written question

Comment: Please put the comment into the question (much easier to read).  It really helps to be as specific as possible in the question.  Show the code you tried, results you got, results you wanted to get, etc.